# Replacing Missing Value

Tags: r, subset, missing-data

I would like to replace the missing value with the existing value in data frame

```
dim(lookup)
```

> [1] 713 686

```
 `head(test)`

ID  DisPrice.1 DisType.1 DisValue.1 DisPrice.2 DisType.2 DisValue.2....  
2     1   3.9         %          0         NA      <NA>         NA.....  
225   2    NA      <NA>         NA       10.9         %          0.....  
264   3    NA      <NA>         NA         NA      <NA>         NA.....  
522   4    NA      <NA>         NA         NA      <NA>         NA.....  
732   5    NA      <NA>         NA         NA      <NA>         NA.....  
1182  6    NA      <NA>         NA         NA      <NA>         NA.....
```

Desired Output:

```
ID  DisPrice.1 DisType.1 DisValue.1 DisPrice.2 DisType.2 DisValue.2.....  
2     1    3.9         %         0         10.9         %         0.....  
225   2    3.9         %         0         10.9         %         0.....  
264   3    3.9         %         0         10.9         %         0.....  
522   4    3.9         %         0         10.9         %         0.....  
732   5    3.9         %         0         10.9         %         0.....  
1182  6    3.9         %         0         10.9         %         0.....
```

Comment: Please `dput` the data for reproducibility

Comment: What if there are missing values and *two different* values in the column. What to replace `NA` with?

Answer (score 2):

Doing all columns in one go. Write a function that copies the non-missing value for each row, and apply that function to each column of the data frame.

```
repl <- function(x) rep(x[!is.na(x)], length(x))
data.frame( apply( df, 2, repl) )
```

Where df is the name of your data frame.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to replace all `NA`s and `<NA>`s:

```
# converte all NA´s to the same "type"
test[is.na(test)] <- "<NA>"

fun <- function(x){
  if(all(!grepl("NA", x))) return(x) # for ID
  rep(x[!grepl("NA", x)], length(x))
}

data.frame(apply(test, 2, fun))
```

hth